# In vmworkstation, NAT local and global interface MAC verification

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

[image: VM workstation virtual network architecture from whitepaper.]

In ARP request, VM vNIC adapter has sender MAC address 00:XX:XX:XX:XX:bb. The IP address of receiver NAT device is 192.168.237.2. The MAC address of NAT from ARP should be 00:XX:XX:XX:12 [image]

While checking the MAC address of NAT in host machine, different MAC exist [image].

Could you please help in ARP response to know which MAC might be showing (likely local). The trace is taken from loopback address of host machine.

Additionally, how to view local interface of NAT device from VMworkstation?

Comment: From VM, ARP table shows 192.168.237.2 has associated MAC address XX:XX:XX:XX:12 which confirms MAC address observed in the trace is of local interface. Is there configuration file in VMworkstation that contain MAC address of local and global interface on NAT device.